# email validation in python pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to highlight all cells in a pandas dataframe column that fail this validity check the color 'red'. Here is my code. In my implementation the whole column email is highlighted red instead of individual cells.

```
# raw data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Username' : ['arenzo', 'brenzo', 'crenzo', 'drenzo'],
              'Email' : ['place1@sales.org', 'place2@sales.org', 'place3@sales.com', 'place4@stack.net']})

# email validity function
def emailcheck (df):
    validcode = (df['Email'].str.contains('@')) & (df['Email'].str.contains('.org', case= False) & (df['Email'].str.contains('sales', case=False)))
    return validcode

def highlight_email(s):
    if emailcheck(df).all():
        color = ''
    else:
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(highlight_email, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['Email']])

# dataframe
Username Email
arenzo   place1@sales.org
brenzo   place2@sales.org
crenzo   place3@sales.com
drenzo   place4@stack.net
# last 2 rows under email column should be highlighted red
```

Comment: but explain your issue..

Comment: @Upsana Mittal the whole email column is highlighted red instead of just the two rows where the email is not valid.

Comment: can you show sample data frame as well? It will help to reproduce the issue and work on it.

Comment: updated the code with sample data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently checking the entire dataframe against your condition

```
validcode = (df['Email'].str.contains('@')) & (df['Email'].str.contains('.org', case= False) & (df['Email'].str.contains('sales', case=False)))
```

then you are testing if all values above are True in your if statement

```
if emailcheck(df).all():
        color = ''
```

This will always return false from your data because some values in the data meet your criteria while others dont. Since the evaluation of that if statement is false, your function will return the color red for every cell. Instead just keep the second function and test against the individual value.

```
def highlight_email(s):
    if '@' in s and '.org' in s and 'sales' in s:
        color = ''
    else:
        color = 'red'
    return 'background-color: {c}'.format(c=color)
```

Comment: @RenzoOlivares, Glad to Help!